# Prove any polygonal function is a finite sum.

Tags: real-analysis, summation, proof-writing

I am trying to prove that any polygonal function $\phi $ is a finite sum $\sum_{j=1}^k a_j \rho (x-b_j)$, for choices of $(a_j) \subset \mathbb{R} $ and $(b_j) \subset [0,1]$.

I have the following definitions:

A function $\phi  \colon [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is said to be polygonal if
it is continuous, and there is a partition of $[0,1]$
\begin{equation}
0= x_0 < x_1 < \cdots < x_n=1
\end{equation}
so that $ \phi  $ is linear on each interval $x _{k-1} < x < x _{k}$, for $k=1 ,2 , \ldots, n $.

and

The RELU  function is $ \rho (x) = \max (0,x) =\frac{x+\sqrt{x^2}}{2}$.

Other than just having proved "For each $\epsilon >0$ there is a polygonal function $\phi $ so that
$\sup _{0\leq x \leq 1} \lvert f(x)  -\phi (x)\rvert < \epsilon .$" I've never encountered a problem like this and would appreciate help/hints.

Comment: Try to prove it for easy cases first. What if the partition is just $0 = x_0 < x_1 = 1$? Then your function is linear and the proof should be easy. What if the partition is $0 = x_0 < x_1 < x_2 = 1$? Also not difficult. Because you can kind of manually do the proof in these easy cases, you should think of trying induction. So you would have to prove: if the claim holds when the size of the partition is $n$, the claim also holds when the size of the partition is $n + 1$.

Answer (score 2):

The problem requires the condition that $\phi(0) = 0$, otherwise it cannot be true. I strongly recommend solving this with linear algebra. (Induction is fine but it doesn't generalize very well)

Given a partition of the kind you described, the set of polygonal functions with respect to this partition forms a finite dimensional vector space of dimension $n$.

The  functions $\rho(x-x_0), \rho(x-x_1), \dots \rho(x-x_{n-1})$ are linearly independent in this space because the functions have distinct support. Since these are $n$ linearly independent functions in a vector space of dimension $n$, they must be a basis for the set of polygonal functions which proves the claim.

Comment: I also recommend drawing a picture of $\rho(x- x_i)$ so you understand the intuition behind this. It's a continuous piecewise linear function with two pieces. It's $0$ to the left of $x_i$ and then "activates" at $x_i$ as a linear function.